# PuTTY - Created new user but can't login with it

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, webserver, root

I can connect to the server with `root` user via ssh, but I can't login with the new user I made named `server`. What I can do though is login to `root`, and then do the `su server` command.

What is the difference between these two? Why does one work and not the other?

Here's the error I get when I try to login with server:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication available. (server sent:
>   public key)

I added an `AllowUsers server` line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The server is expecting an SSH key for that user, and one does not exist.

When you log in as root, your likely putting in a user name and password from the keyboard, which does not need a private key on the server.

For your new user however, it sounds like you've set putty to sign in only using an SSH key/cert , but have not created the corresponding private key in the "server" users home directory.

These links should help you sort it out:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Make sure that you also set the auto username correctly in

"connection->data"

in the putty settings for your session.

Also be aware, that if you generate the certificate on windows using the putty tools, you need to convert the certificate before you can use it on Linux, this also is true the other way, if you gerate the certificate on Linux then copy it to windows for putty to use, you need to convert it the other way.

This link explains the process to use to convert them:

http://meinit.nl/using-your-openssh-private-key-in-putty